# angular-cli: how do I configure webpack?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Ok, I'm very pleased that angular-cli exists. Hooray for standards!

However, I am a little disturbed that webpack is operating somewhere in the depths of the angular-cli code and there is not, for example, a webpack.config.js.

What gives? How do I configure loaders? Plugins? Is `ng serve` using the webpack server in the background?

Can someone elucidate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure webpack with angular-cli presently and it sounds like it's not coming soon: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I configure webpack alias using angular2-cli?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that things from cli.json file inside your project.