# Angular-Highcharts using Angular-CLI; where do I add a Webpack alias?

Tags: angular, highcharts, webpack, angular-cli

Following the guide for [integrating angular2-highcharts with Angular2](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-webpack-starter-and-angular2-highcharts/commit/fffbebfd7974f808242dbbb8eccdfc108dde72cf), they're calling for setting a Webpack alias for `highcharts/highstock.src.js`, like:

```
alias: {
        highcharts$: "highcharts/highstock.src.js"
      },
```

According to one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054324/angular-cli-how-do-i-configure-webpack), there's no way to configure Webpack with Angular-CLI.

I tried running without the alias, and I get an error which I'm not sure is related:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/graph/graph.component.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/bradley/Documents/Work/megastore/src/app/graph/graph.component.ts (8,31): Cannot find module 'highcharts/highcharts-3d'.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (/Users/bradley/Documents/Work/megastore/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:116:15)
    at /Users/bradley/Documents/Work/megastore/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:141:17
 @ ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts 14:0-57
 @ ./src/app/core/core.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

Is there a way set this alias to get angular2-highcharts working in my project?

Answer (score 2):

Although this isn't covered in the `angular2-highcharts` documentation, I solved it when trying to implement styled mode (see [`gevgeny/angular2-highcharts#115`](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/115#issuecomment-267094285)). You can alias `highcharts` in your `src/tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  ...,
  "paths": {
    ...,
    "highcharts": ["../node_modules/highcharts/highstock.js"] 
  }
}
```